# user intervention in a php while loop

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, user-input

Using php to build a quiz which requires a while loop to scroll through the questions array in turn. How can the user activate 'next question' without jquery? Can I somehow jump to an anchor higher up the while loop to increment a variable? The messy alternative is to create a new page for each question with hyperlinks.

Comment: PHP is going to create the entire page and send it to the browser. There can't really be any user interaction without making another request, whether that is AJAX or a page reload/load new page.

Comment: If you can show an example to illustrate more specifically what you're trying to do, it will be easier for people to suggest some possible solutions, or maybe even answer with something that will work for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: I guess it really isn't possible as I had already thought. I cannot elaborate any more on the original question. Thanks.